# Application integration with JIRA using API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm working on POC for integrating JIRA board / issue / story into my application.

Front-end is Angular and back-end uses JAVA (Spring MVC). JIRA is hosted on-premise.

I was searching in the JIRA developer page, but it is bit confusing which to use.

I want to know about following things usage.

- JIRA Java Rest client
- JIRA Agile Rest API
- JIRA Maven dependency

Kindly help me understand the JIRA library.

Comment: Whoever downvote please note just pasting random link from Google will not give a solution

Comment: I didn't downvote but is it directed towards me as I'm the only one who took time to give you as many details as possible - but yet you still require more!

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me to choose between `JIRA Java Rest Client (JRJC)`, I don't see many updates on that section and if you find any issues then you might have to spend time in finding alternative ways to resolve that problem.

If you look at `JIRA Agile REST APIs`, these should be the best of the possible options that one can opt for amongst the available options (the same that you've listed in your own question). If you choose to opt `JIRA REST APIs` over the other options, then any issue that you face might be handled either by the `JIRA Atlassian` Documentation or the `Atlassian` Developer community (who are always ready to provide solutions to the best of their knowledge).

**EDIT-1:**

**JIRA REST Java Client:**

Resources:

1. [Community question explaining the usage](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JIRA-REST-client-simple-example/qaq-p/464118)
2. [Working `JRJC` `pom.xml`](https://bitbucket.org/jaysee00/jrjc-example-client/src/e01e0da6d72e06aa21b0a8fe5c23d62b97192ca9/standalone/pom.xml?at=master&_ga=2.198169839.1972856013.1528703156-665356806.1508320943&fileviewer=file-view-default)
3. [Working `JRJC` client](https://bitbucket.org/jaysee00/jrjc-example-client/src/e01e0da6d72e06aa21b0a8fe5c23d62b97192ca9/standalone/src/main/java/com/atlassian/jira/examples/Main.java?at=master&_ga=2.198169839.1972856013.1528703156-665356806.1508320943&fileviewer=file-view-default)

**JIRA REST APIs:**

Resources:

1. [Atlassian Documentation with examples on using JIRA REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/)

**JIRA Maven Dependency:**

Resources:

1. [Atlassian Community question answering `JRJC` Maven dependency](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Rest-Java-Client-Library-maven-dependency/qaq-p/504202)
2. [What dependency do we need to add for JIRA Maven integration?](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/adding-the-maven-dependency/)

Hope this helps in making your own decisions. If you need further assistance, please do let me know!

Comment: it didn't completely give a solution

Comment: Don't you think that is too much of an ask in just one answer without even giving a try from your end?